# Is there research on the special values of the zeta function outside the integers?

Tags: zeta-functions

This question quotes from this [article](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/pschnei/publ/pap/beilin.pdf), but I've noticed this pattern in the literature I've read.

> "The values or
>   better the leading coefficients at integral arguments of the L-functions of algebraic varieties over number fields seem to be closely related to the global arithmetical geom­etry of these varieties"

That is, the Riemann zeta function takes on special values
$$ \zeta(2n)=\mathbb{Q}^\times\times\pi^{2n} \quad \zeta(1-2n)\in\mathbb{Q}^\times $$
for $n\in\mathbb{Z_{>0}}$. The Dedekind zeta function of some number field has a special value at the residue on $s=1$, and etc. etc. up to theory I consider to be cutting edge, e.g. the Beilinson Conjectures and so on. I've even noticed *half-integer* arguments, but nothing more complicated than that.

**Question**: Is there any research on the zeta function, Riemann or otherwise, at non-integral values?

**EDIT** I'm more interested in research that would motivate someone to look for non-integral arguments.

Comment: related question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2441075/values-of-riemann-zeta-at-rational-non-integer-points

Comment: I appreciate this link, especially since it reminds me of the interesting work done on polylogarithms, although I am interested in any _research_ along non-integral arguments. That is, I'm looking for the questions and contexts which motivate people to look for these values, perhaps with no closed-form at all, and not just examples of them. I can accept how my question title can mislead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One research paper that might qualify for what you are searching: [On the values of the Riemann zeta-function at rational arguments](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01109799/document), S. Kanemitsu, Y. Tanigawa and M. Yoshimoto (2001).

> We give a closed form evaluation of Ramanujan’s type of the values of
>   the Riemann zeta-function at positive rational arguments in the
>   critical strip.

Comment: Yes, this does look interesting. I'll read it.